# Unable to insert data into Apache Derby database using Java/JSP

Tags: java, sql, jsp, glassfish, derby

I am unable to insert data into an Apache Derby database using Java and JSP on a Glassfish server. When I try and do so, I get the error:

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: The number of values assigned is not the same as the number of specified or implied columns.

However I cannot see where in my code the error is, since as far as I can tell I am using the right values. The relevant segment of code is:

```
 String sql2 = "INSERT INTO APP.USERS (emailAddress, firstName, lastName, password) VALUES ('?', '?', '?', '?', '?')";
        PreparedStatement statement2 = connection.prepareStatement(sql2);
        int test = 0;
        statement2.setInt(0, test);
        statement2.setString(1, emailAddress);
        statement2.setString(2, firstName);
        statement2.setString(3, lastName);
        statement2.setString(4, password);
        statement2.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Just change this `statement2.setInt(1, test);
        statement2.setString(2, emailAddress);
        statement2.setString(3, firstName);
        statement2.setString(4, lastName);
        statement2.setString(5, password);` you cannot insert from `0` start from `1` for 1st value ,2nd for second and so on..

Comment: At first this appeared to work, but now when I try I get:

The column position '1' is out of range.  The number of columns for this ResultSet is '0'.

The revised code looks like this:

String sql2 = "INSERT INTO APP.USERS (emailAddress, firstName, lastName, password) VALUES ('?', '?', '?', '?')";
            PreparedStatement s2 = connection.prepareStatement(sql2);
            st2.setString(1, emailAddress);
            s2.setString(2, firstName);
            s2.setString(3, lastName);
            s2.setString(4, password);
            s2.executeUpdate();

Comment: add full stacktrace in your question it would help to identify where error exist .

Answer (score 0):

Don't put the question marks in single quotation marks. Your `VALUES` clause should look like `VALUES(?,?,?,?)`